# `apply_async` consider different date format when task create

Tags: python, celery, django-celery, flower

> celery version : v4.2.1 + rabbitMQ

When i set task using `apply_asyc` it is considering different date time format.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=+5)
RunScheduledScrape.apply_async(args=[program.id,new_task.id],eta=now)
```

Look below image for date time which is in UTC format.

[image]

when i check this task in flower then it has different time and task never execute.

There is a **`T`** between date and time due to this task is never executed.

[image]

Even i tried to change date format and try to give it in ETA , but is consider same format.

Answer (score 1):

Your celery app instance will have a `now` function that you should use so that you have a proper time zone setting on your datetime, but why not just call this with `countdown`?

```
RunScheduledScrape.apply_async(args=[program.id,new_task.id], countdown=300)  
# 300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

Comment: still task is not execute.